# Broadband file transfer bottleneck

Tags: file-transfer, bandwidth, isp

I am transferring a video (about 500 MB) created for a school project to my classmate's NAS box over our broadband connections.

She has a 15 Mbps down and I have 15 Mbps up, according to multiple tests on sites like speedtest.net.

However, the file transfer is happening at a dismal 500 Kbps.  I can't image what the bottleneck is.  I don't believe it can be attributed to the internal home networks.  I have no other upload activity.

Could anyone suggest what the bottle neck is?

Comment: When you say "500 Kbps" do you actually mean 500KB/s? Theoretically, you should be getting about 1,740KB/s.

Comment: I mean 500 Kilo bits per second.  I believe Kbps, kbps, Kb/s all mean the same thing.  Lowercase 'b' for bits, uppercase 'B' for bytes, so no, I don't mean 500KB/s.

Comment: What software reports file transfer rates in bits per second?

Comment: I am an idiot.  I misread the transfer rate. Thanks David.